# i am not getting an output of reversed array from my code below

Tags: java, arrays

What's wrong with my code below, i am not getting an output , and there isn't any error in my code either..

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter your data");
    int n = sc.nextInt ();
    int a[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = a.length- 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        System.out.print (a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you providing the necessary inputs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first look nothing looks wrong with code. The input might be wrong however.

Note that the first integer passed determines the size of the array.

**Input:** *One after the other on the console separated by Enter key*

`5` ⏎
`10` ⏎
`20` ⏎
`30` ⏎
`40` ⏎
`50` ⏎

**Output:**

`50 40 30 20 10`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine at it is. You are probably not providing the input in your console. This would make it a bit clearer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter next number: ");
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
```